# Relationship between column values

Tags: sqlite

So i have two columns, `employeeID` and `ReportsTo` which is the `EmployeeID` the employee reports to. If i were to find the `employeeID` who had the largest number of employees report to them how would this be done?

Comment: Easily, using a JOIN and COUNT. What have you tried so far? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

You have to group the record on ReportsTo column and count the number of employee. You can use below query. this query will gives the records of no of employee assign to Reports To.

```
select COUNT(distinct EmployeeID) as EmployeeCount,ReportsTo  from TableName group by ReportsTo order by EmployeeCount desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your question clearly. As per my understand this query may be helpful.

`SELECT count(ReportsTo) as largest_number from tablename GROUP BY ReportsTo ORDER BY largest_number DESC LIMIT 0,1`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ReportsTo,COUNT(*) AS NoOfReporters 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY ReportsTo 
ORDER BY NoOfReporters DESC
```

I assume EmployeeID as primary key of your table so there wont be duplication of records.
ReportsTo is the EmployeeID to whom the other Employee Reports and NoOfReporters are the employee who reports to him.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
select top 1 ReportsTo, count(distinct employeeID)
from InsertYourTableName
group by ReportsTo
order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this (considered `ReportsTo` and `EmployeeID` combination has unique entries):

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(ReportsTo) as NoOfEmp, EmployeeID 
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY EmployeeID
ORDER by NoOfEmp DESC
```